# Installing Drivers from CD on Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: 12.10, drivers

I've recently got a new PC & installed dual-boot Win XP & Ubuntu 12.10 I've installed all the proprietory drivers from cd/dvd in Windows (on seperate partition) but I'm not sure how to go about doing this in Ubuntu.

I've searched for info but haven't been able to make much sense of the other threads. I'm very commandline inexperienced & new to installing stuff on Ubuntu other than through software centre so any help would be appreciated.

The DVD/CD drivers I have to install are: Gigabyte AMD 9/8/7-series Utility DVD, Club-3d graphics Driver CD& Tenda Wireless Network Adapter Driver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please forget any method you used for Windows. Linux (and thus Ubuntu) is a complete other ballgame.

Linux uses generic drivers. This means that IF hardware is supported by Linux the drivers are included with the system and during installation Linux will install those drivers for you.

For the motherboard you need no drivers. That Utility DVD you have is worthless when using Linux. Unless there are documents on there (but the drivers and software are useless).

For graphics cards we have native drivers but also drivers from the videocard manufacturers. Linux/Ubuntu will install the native driver and after installing show you drivers it has in its arsenal that are provided by 3rd party manufacturers. System settings -> software sources -> additional drivers:

[image]

The wireless card. Here: http://linuxwireless.org/en/users/Devices/USB it says `rt2800usb Tenda W311U 0x148f 0x3070` (I assume this is the one you have too since it is not listed elsewhere) and the driver rt2800usb is listed here as supported: http://linuxwireless.org/en/users/Drivers In the past you might have needed to install the windows drivers with a program called ndiswrapper but this is getting rarer and rarer!

Comment: Excellent, Thanks Rinzwind
Looks like I don't need to do anything. Cheers

Comment: no problem @LudditeSavant If it suits your question do not forget to upvote and/or accept this answer :)